# Interact with dates as pandas dataframe column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Let's take these two sample dataframes :

```
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4],'2021-12-01':[True]*4,'2021-12-02':[True]*4, '2021-12-03':[True]*4})


   ID  2021-12-01  2021-12-02  2021-12-03
0   1        True        True        True
1   2        True        True        True
2   3        True        True        True
3   4        True        True        True


df_bad_dates = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,4],'Date_min':["2021-12-03","2021-12-01","2021-10-28"],'Date_max':["2021-12-08","2021-12-01","2022-09-01"]})
df_bad_dates["Date_min"] = df_bad_dates["Date_min"].astype('datetime64')
df_bad_dates["Date_max"] = df_bad_dates["Date_max"].astype('datetime64')

   ID   Date_min   Date_max
0   1 2021-12-03 2021-12-08
1   1 2021-12-01 2021-12-01
2   4 2021-10-28 2022-09-01
```

I would like to put a `False` value in `df_dates` where the date in the column name is between `Date_min` and `Date_max` for the corresponding `ID` in `df_bad_dates`. I can do it with a for loop but it is very slow with my real big dataframe. Would you know please an efficient way to do ?

Feel free to advise me a better way to stock ranges of days for which I can(not) do something

Expected output :

```
   ID  2021-12-01  2021-12-02  2021-12-03
0   1       False        True       False
1   2        True        True        True
2   3        True        True        True
3   4       False       False       False
```

Comment: I am not so sure if I understand. In your expected output, why do you expect a `True` value at the ID=1 and at the column `2021-12-02`?

Comment: Because ```2021-12-02``` is not between ```Date_min``` and ```Date_max``` in ```df_bad_dates``` for ```ID``` 1 :) Thanks for your comment